# transform integral of a series

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

I am given the following:

> $1. \int_0^{\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}exp(-n^2\pi t)t^{s-1}dt$ where $s\in \mathbb R$

How do I derive the following form of the integral above ?

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n^2\pi)^s}\int_0^{\infty}exp(-t)t^{s-1}dt$$

I tried to rearrange $(1)$ and use partial integration but that didn't work out.

Would appreciate any help/hints

Comment: You surely want $\exp(-n^2\pi t)$ in the first integral. Now make the substitution $t'=-n^2\pi t$.

Comment: Please fix the typo(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @LordSharkTheUnknown by substituting $t'={ n^2\pi }t$ we obtain$$\int_0^{\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\exp(-n^2\pi t)t^{s-1}dt{=\int_0^{\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\exp(-t')\left({t'\over n^2\pi}\right)^{s-1}d({t'\over n^2\pi})\\=\int_0^{\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left({1\over n^2\pi }\right)^s\exp(-t'){(t')}^{s-1}dt'\\=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_0^{\infty}\left({1\over n^2\pi }\right)^s\exp(-t'){(t')}^{s-1}dt'\\=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left({1\over n^2\pi }\right)^s\int_0^{\infty}\exp(-t)\cdot t^{s-1}dt}$$